# Screenshot of view containing RMMapView results in tiled image

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, mapbox

When I try to take a screenshot of a `UIView` that contains an instance of `RMMapView`, the resulting image shows the `RMMapView` as just default tiles. The build in `takeSnapshot` and `takeSnapshotAnIncludeOverlay:(BOOL)overlay` do not suffice as I need other subviews included. Any of the MapBox devs have any advice? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I figured a 'hack' way out to do this, but hope the mapbox devs can shine light on the core issue here: screenshots of a view containing a `RMMapView` don't work.

The workaround is as follows:

- create a dummy `UIView` and add another dummy `UIView`, dummy2 to it.
- create as many `UIImageView`'s as you need to take screenshots of the different subviews visible in the main view.
- create an `UIImageView` to take a screenshot of the mapbox map and blur set image to hide the thin lines their SDK adds.
- add all `UIImageView`'s to dummy2, add dummy2 to dummy1.
- set dummy1 to hidden, and add to main view.
- take screenshot of dummy2 and remove dummy1 from view to deallocate.

There you have it, a nice `UIImage` of the map and the other subviews in view. Ridiculous workaround? Absolutely.